# Resolving how to give an attribute in a class in Python

Tags: python, class, optimization

I have the following class:

```
class Point(object):
    __slots__= ("x","y","z","data","classification")
    def __init__(self,x,y,z,n=None):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)
        self.data = [self.x,self.y,self.z]

    def set_classification(self,n):
        self.classification = n

p = Point(10,20,30)
p.data
[10.0, 20.0, 30.0]
p.set_classification(0)
p.data
[10.0, 20.0, 30.0]
```

I have the following questions:

First, the parameters to create the Point object are `x,y`, and `z`. `Classification` is an accessory parameter (some time is report inside the file other no). I wish to find a way, if it's possible, to have
`p.data = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0]` when classification is set or `p.data = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]` when classification is not set.

By the way, I use `set_classification`

```
def set_classification(self,n):
      self.classification = n
```

Comment: you can add
`if(self.classification == 1):
    self.data.append(50)` in your `set_classification` method right after you set it

Comment: Note if you're just learning Python, I very much doubt you need `__slots__`. That's an advanced feature which should only be used by people who know what they're doing.

Comment: Thnaks Daniel, I am following some example i read in internt and i wish to build my own class. each suggestion is always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to handle classification instead:

```
class Point(object):
    __slots__= ("x", "y", "z", "data", "_classification")
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)
        self.data = [self.x,self.y,self.z]

    @property
    def classification(self):
        return getattr(self, '_classification', None)

    @classification.setter
    def classification(self, value):
        self._classification = value
        if value:
            self.data = self.data[:3] + [value]
        else:
            self.data = self.data[:3]
```

This sets up a getter and a setter for a `classification` attribute; accessing the `classification` attribute translates into the first method being called. Setting the `classification` attribute translates in the setter, the second method, being called instead:

```
p = Point(1, 2, 3)
p.classification = 50  # calls the second `classification` method, the setter, for you.
print p.classification # calls the first `classification` method, the getter.
```

I picked the `classification` attribute as the property here, but you could make `data` a property instead as well. Which one you make into a property depends on usage patterns and intent. If `classification` is rarely changed, making it the property would be more efficient.

Comment: hey Martijn, thanks. I was looking about @property in internet, but I am honest to say It's not clear for me.

Comment: I tested and i got this error message
p = Point(10,20,30)
p.classification(50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Gianni it's a property. you can call it with `p.classification = 50`

Comment: @Gianni: You use it not as a method but as an attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks Martjin.=, I start to understand and happy to learn everyday (thanks for your help). I have just last question to understand better the use of @property. If i wish to add a new parameter es "location" (numeric value), Do i need create a @location.setter? How i can use in this case self.data? Do i need write all possible combination?

Comment: @Gianni: the setter is entirely optional. If you only need to have read access, no setter is needed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the right way to add a new "location" parameter. Do i need add a new @property def location(self)....?

Answer (score 2):

Getter and setter methods are generally frowned upon. You can use a property to achieve this, however I'd recommened to always include `classification` in your return value, just because other parts of your script might expect that `data` is always a 4-item list. APIs should be consistent.

Here's my take on it using a property:

```
class Point(object):
    __slots__= ("x", "y", "z", "data", "classification")
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, n=None):  ## what's n for?
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)

        self.classification = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.classification:
            return [self.x, self.y, self.z, self.classification]
        else:
            return [self.x, self.y, self.z]

p = Point(10, 20, 30)
print p.data   ## [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]
p.classification = 50.0
print p.data   ## [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0]
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I start to understand. Just one question. If i wish to add a new parameter es: "location" do i need to add if self.location?

Comment: @Gianni If you want to include a new optional attribute to the return value of the `data` property, then yes, you'd need to modify the if statement accordingly.